# How to solve below error occured in app-certification in Windows store?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, publish, windows-store, app-certification-kit

I created UWP Xamarin.Forms based application and than I try to submit it on Windows store but when I try to publish my application it pass pre-processing
but in certification step it gives me below error:

**Please take the following action**

We reviewed your submission and identified some changes that are needed before we can publish or update the app. Please make these changes and resubmit your app. For more information, contact reportapp@microsoft.com Please include your app ID so we can act quickly.

**App Policies:** 10.1.2 Mixed Reality Functionality

**Notes To Developer**

The app submission inaccurately claims immersive Mixed Reality (MR) support. For the next update, make sure MR capabilities are accurately reported when the app is submitted in Dev Center: Display Mode (under Properties) correctly identifies only supported MR devices.

The app metadata inaccurately claims support for Mixed Reality capable hardware.
Please make sure you accurately report the supported hardware when you submit your app in Dev Center.

Please remove the following hardware from System requirements (under Properties):
· Windows Mixed Reality motion controllers
· Windows Mixed Reality immersive headset

**Tested Devices:** Lenovo MIIX 520

Please Note
Your current certification results might differ from earlier submissions because Microsoft Store policy requirements can change over time. When policies change, we might re-test according to the new requirements regardless of the submission type. Please always rely on your most recent certification results.

Can anybody please look into this and suggest me what should I have to change in my package or submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have accidentally enabled(Checked) them.
So, Open last submission or Update your Submission, Click **Properties** >> scroll down to *System requirements* >> then UNCHECK *Windows Mixed Reality motion controllers* & *Windows Mixed Reality immersive headset* if your app doesn't need these items.

[image]

Comment: I also try with that but it shows me this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hRy-MfxnslLZlPy5h0anQhFYZjmbJ52G) Can you please look into this and suggest me what should I have to change?

Comment: What devices you selected for *Device family availability* inside Packages section?

Comment: I select PC inside package section but when I try with uncheck that it works for me. Thanks @MKH for help.

Comment: Glad it helped, I think Checking *PC* or *HoloLens* in Properties >> *Display mode* section may require to check MR options.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same certification report for some PWA app. On the **Submission - Properties** checkbox "*Windows Mixed Reality immersive headset*" was mandatory.
Turns out it was because on input "*This experience is designed to run in an immersive (not a 2D) view on the following Windows Mixed Reality platform(s):*" **PC** option was checked.

After turning it off, the "*Windows Mixed Reality immersive headset*" option is no longer mandatory, and can be unchecked.

[image]

(...way below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the App submission checklist Properties section, insure that you haven't checked any of the mixed reality system requirements.

Comment: Thanks for response. I actually try to uncheck that checkbox but when I uncheck that it status change from the complete to incomplete. Can you please suggest what should I have to do.?

Comment: share what all the settings you have on that page - there should be a clue in the incomplete message.